# $.ajax missing some data on post to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, httprequest

I have a problem where some of my data is not getting through to php. I think the problem lies in ajax sending it. I send about 10 attributes, from which some are strings and some are integers. This is just simplified example of what I did. Few of the values given that it misses are integers, I think. And some values are got from cordova.Localstorage with `storage.getItem("itemkeyname");` There's no problem with connection, because I get at least error message back saying "missing data" etc, etc.. 
I've tried PHP's isset() instead of empty(), which didn't change anything.
var_dump() returns array of send attributes, but few last attributes are cut-off or missing.

```
//when submitbtn is pressed
$("#submitbtn").click(function () {

    // First I get data from input elements from page
    $name = $("#name").val();
    $name2 = $("#name2").val();

    //debug to see $name's value
    alert("name: " + $name + ", name2: " + $name2);

    // then I check it's not empty/null
    if ($name && $name2) {
        //then call ajax and send data to server
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:1234/phpfile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $name,
                name2: $name2
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $output = JSON.stringify(err);
                alert($output);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On the server side phpfile.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//store missing data on array
$data_missing = array();

if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $data_missing[] = "name";
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
}

if(empty($_POST['name2'])) {
    $data_missing[] = "name2";
} else {
    $name2 = trim($_POST['name2']);
}

//check there's no data missing
if(empty($data_missing)) {

    //do stuff

} else {
    echo 'missing data: ';
    foreach($data_missing as $missing) {
        echo '$missing , ';
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: At the beginning of your PHP, try to `var_dump($_POST);`to see what you receive. You can check what is sent too using the developer tool embedded in browsers

Comment: `empty()` is not a good test anyways. `'0'` and `0` both count as "empty"... empty's name is really stupid. should be more like "false-ish".

Comment: ok, I got array of things I sent, last String is cutoff only having 3 digits instead of 5. And I think there was few attributes after that are missing. Is there a limit how big or many attributes I can send?

Also I'm not sending zeros, so I don't think that's a problem now. I could though check in the if($_POST['name'] > 0) {}

Answer (score 0):

1. echo '$missing , ' won't work should be echo "$missing , "
2. In your JS code the dataType is defined as "text" (plain), while PHP defines its response as text/html.
3. Try to check the input values as:

   if( !isset($_POST["name"]) || strlen(trim($_POST["name"])) == 0 ) {
       $data_missing[] = "name";
   }

Comment: @J-ho: I tested this code with the two fields provided - I've got all values on the server side.

Comment: These didn't help my case. I use 10 variables that I sent and the last one gets left off. var_dump() returns array of my variables, but the last one is missing most of the time or missing few numbers. I was wondering if Ajax is sending only some of the data, because I can see my data being filled before sending it.

Comment: I am intrigued already. Is it possible to get the full code? (form + form action) I want to reproduce the problem.